# Problem with background-image. And its size: content property

Tags: css, background-image

```css
.section--7__photos {
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 70rem;
  margin: 0 8%;
  background: url("https://ableton-production.imgix.net/about/photo-8.jpg?crop=right&dpr=1.5&fit=crop&h=250&ixjsv=1.1.3&q=66&w=417") no-repeat top 0% center/ contain;
}
.section--7__text {
  margin: 0 8%;
  padding: 8%;
  background-color: #11c01f;
}
.section--7__text p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="section--7__container">
          <div class="section--7__photos"></div>
          <div class="section--7__text">
            <p class="text--main__1">
              Lorum...
            </p>        
          </div>
```

Im trying to fit background-image in a container that has size dependant on viewport width.
But its height in not equal of height of a image itself. There is a gap beetwen cointainer holding image and its next sibling (green text field).
[image]

```
<div class="section--7__container">
          <div class="section--7__photos"></div>
          <div class="section--7__text">
            <p class="text--main__1">
              Lorum...
            </p>        
          </div>
```

CSS

```
.section--7__photos {
  height: 50vw;
  max-height: 70rem;
  margin: 0 8%;
  background: url("Images/photo-8.jpg") no-repeat top 0% center/ contain;
}
.section--7__text {
  margin: 0 8%;
  padding: 8%;
  background-color: #11c01f;
}
.section--7__text p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: cover instead of contain then?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem using another image so please could you create a runnable snippet with your image - and check that it shows the problem. (are you certain your image doesn't have a little white bit at the bottom?)

Comment: code work nice with me, I thought the problem was in your image try another image

Answer (score -1):

```
position:relative; position:absolute;
```

Hello if you need to add text over an image add css rules

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).